# How to test SCSI drives faulty or not?

Tags: ibm, scsi, diagnostic

I have 10 scsi drives which are used. How do I test them to ensure they are working correctly? Some have red stickers presumably indicating they are faulty. The server I have access to is an IBM with ServeRAID 7k controller.

The server has a serveraid support CD for configuring the raid controller, but not any specific diagnostics software. Can I run diagnostics for the drives from Windows Server 2008 which is installed on one of the servers?

Comment: Connect them to a system and run [badblocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks)

Comment: Are these really old parallel SCSI drives, or are they SAS disks?

Comment: [smartmontools](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) should be your first stop lacking something specifically better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only familiar with the Unix world tools, you can use sgtools and mostly sg_logs to peek at the disk status. You can see different pages where the most important is page 0x2f which shows "Informational Exceptions", esssentially SMART. If that page shows asc/ascq of 0x0 than the disks don't think they are dead. Beyond that you'll need to have better understanding of disks to make a decision.

The other tool to use is sg_senddiag which can utilize SEND DIAGNOSTICS commands to tell the drive to test itself and then to monitor the test state with sg_logs again (forgot the page number for test results, use page 0 to find the page number).